# Error "The referenced file '/_catalogs/mycustompage.master' is not allowed on this page." when using custom master page in application page

Tags: 2013, master-page, application-pages

I am trying to use customer master page in my application page but getting following error:

**Error**

> The referenced file '/_catalogs/mycustompage.master' is not allowed on
>   this page.

**Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SomeCode.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomeCode.Code" MasterPageFile="~/_catalogs/mycustompage.master" %>
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had to include the master page (.master) in the project and then reference the master file in the application page for it to work.

Add a Layouts scoped folder and add the master file to that folder. Make sure you actually add the master file to your project and reference from there.

[image]

Comment: But what about CSS, JS and images used in master page including any user controls? I manually copied master page in Layouts folder and now it is giving me error that some user control doesn't exist. If I use your method will it work?

Comment: I'd recommend testing with a basic master page to see if it works or not and then build upon it.